# Javascipt component not coming render as pdf

Tags: visualforce, javascript, renderas

I am working on a visualforce page and have used javascript to add a row dynamically. All are coming in the pdf except that javascript column.

Below is the javascript sippet that is not loading:

```
<apex:page controller="Controller" renderAs="pdf">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--SLDS STYLESHEET STATIC RESOURCE-->
            <apex:slds />
                <body>
```

Comment: This is another example of abusive behavior. Please stop removing code from your posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this document: [Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm).

> - Don’t use standard components that aren’t easily formatted for print,
>   or form elements such as inputs or buttons, or any component that
>   requires JavaScript to be formatted.
> - PDF rendering doesn’t support
>   JavaScript-rendered content.

Generate your own HTML in visualforce page instead.